# Blazor WebAssembly App with Individual Accounts and ASP.NET Core Hosted - Token request - "error": "unauthorized_client"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Creating a new `Blazor WebAssembly App` with `Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.9.4` with these specifications: `Target Framework .NET 5.0`, `Authentication Type Individual Accounts` and `ASP.NET Core Hosted`:

[image]

Gives a Server project with these `NuGet`s at version `5.0.5`:

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI

Startup.cs contains this code:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddIdentityServerJwt();
```

Reading the blog post `ASP.NET Core Authentication with IdentityServer4` from Microsoft I should be able to retrieve a token with a sample request that looks like this:

```
POST /connect/token HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5000
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 958df72b-663c-5638-052a-aed41ba0dbd1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=password&username=Mike%40Contoso.com&password=MikesPassword1!&client_id=myClient&scope=myAPIs
```

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-authentication-with-identityserver4/

Creating a request that looks like that but for the solution created:

```
POST /connect/token HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:44388
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 153

grant_type=password&username=example%40example.com&password=Password1&client_id=WebApplication4.Client&scope=WebApplication4.ServerAPI%20openid%20profile
```

This request returns HTTP Status 400 Bad Request with body:

```
{
    "error": "unauthorized_client"
}
```

[image]

I'm pretty sure the values are correct since I got `client_id` and `scope` from the request used to sign in to the web application. That flow does not use `grant_type=password` though. Example request from login:

```
https://localhost:44388/Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=/connect/authorize/callback?client_id=WebApplication4.Client&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44388%2Fauthentication%2Flogin-callback&response_type=code&scope=WebApplication4.ServerAPI%20openid%20profile&state=12345&code_challenge=12345&code_challenge_method=S256&response_mode=query
```

Confirmation that the user exists and works:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR:**

Remove this from `appsettings.json`:

```
"Clients": {
  "WebApplication4.Client": {
    "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
  }
}
```

Edit `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.Clients.AddIdentityServerSPA("WebApplication4.Client", builder =>
        {
            builder.WithRedirectUri("/authentication/login-callback");
            builder.WithLogoutRedirectUri("/authentication/logout-callback");
        });
        //Or Duende.IdentityServer.Models.Client
        options.Clients.Add(new IdentityServer4.Models.Client
        {
            ClientId = "WebApplication4.Integration",
            AllowedGrantTypes = { GrantType.ResourceOwnerPassword },
            //Use Configuration.GetSection("MySecretValue").Value; to get a value from appsettings.json
            ClientSecrets = { new Secret("MySecretValue".Sha256()) },
            AllowedScopes = { "WebApplication4.ServerAPI", "openid", "profile" }
        });
    });
```

This request will work:

```
POST /connect/token HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:44388
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 168

grant_type=password&username=example%40example.com&password=Password1!&client_id=WebApplication4.Integration&scope=WebApplication4.ServerAPI&client_secret=MySecretValue
```

**Long answer:**

I started out with trying to get a better error messages with Logging.

I added the code below to `public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)` in
`Program.cs`:

```
.ConfigureLogging(logging =>
{
    logging.ClearProviders();
    logging.AddConsole();
})
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0

When debugging I could then show output from the Server application when I made the request. It looked like this:

```
info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint for /connect/token
info: IdentityServer4.Events.DefaultEventService[0]
      {
        "ClientId": "WebApplication4.Client",
        "AuthenticationMethod": "NoSecret",
        "Category": "Authentication",
        "Name": "Client Authentication Success",
        "EventType": "Success",
        "Id": 1010,
        "ActivityId": "8000000a-0000-8f00-b63f-84710c7967bb",
        "TimeStamp": "2021-04-29T11:47:07Z",
        "ProcessId": 8436,
        "LocalIpAddress": "::1:44388",
        "RemoteIpAddress": "::1"
      }
fail: IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator[0]
      Client not authorized for resource owner flow, check the AllowedGrantTypes setting{ client_id = WebApplication4.Client }, details: {
        "ClientId": "WebApplication4.Client",
        "ClientName": "WebApplication4.Client",
        "GrantType": "password",
        "Raw": {
          "grant_type": "password",
          "username": "example@example.com",
          "password": "***REDACTED***",
          "client_id": "WebApplication4.Client",
          "scope": "WebApplication4.ServerAPI"
        }
      }
info: IdentityServer4.Events.DefaultEventService[0]
      {
        "ClientId": "WebApplication4.Client",
        "ClientName": "WebApplication4.Client",
        "Endpoint": "Token",
        "GrantType": "password",
        "Error": "unauthorized_client",
        "Category": "Token",
        "Name": "Token Issued Failure",
        "EventType": "Failure",
        "Id": 2001,
        "ActivityId": "8000000a-0000-8f00-b63f-84710c7967bb",
        "TimeStamp": "2021-04-29T11:47:07Z",
        "ProcessId": 8436,
        "LocalIpAddress": "::1:44388",
        "RemoteIpAddress": "::1"
      }
```

The error message to look at is `Client not authorized for resource owner flow, check the AllowedGrantTypes setting{ client_id = WebApplication4.Client }`.

[image]

With this error message I found this Question:

[Question about ASP.NET Core 3 Identity / Identity Server / SPA support for Resource Owner Password Grant Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57899926/question-about-asp-net-core-3-identity-identity-server-spa-support-for-resou)

There I could read

> found that the allowed grant type of password was not being added when
> the profile is set to IdentityServerSPA.

Looking at `appsettings.json` the application uses that profile:

```
"IdentityServer": {
  "Clients": {
    "WebApplication4.Client": {
      "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
    }
  }
},
```

Looking at `Microsoft Application profiles` what it actually does is this:

- The redirect_uri defaults to /authentication/login-callback.
- The post_logout_redirect_uri defaults to
  /authentication/logout-callback.
- The set of scopes includes the openid, profile, and every scope
  defined for the APIs in the app.
- The set of allowed OIDC response types is id_token token or each of
  them individually (id_token, token).
- The allowed response mode is fragment.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-5.0#application-profiles

Before starting to modify this I visited the URL `https://localhost:44388/.well-known/openid-configuration` to get the current configuration. It looked like this and specifically says `grant_types_supported: ...password`:

```
{
    "issuer": "https://localhost:44388",
    "jwks_uri": "https://localhost:44388/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks",
    "authorization_endpoint": "https://localhost:44388/connect/authorize",
    "token_endpoint": "https://localhost:44388/connect/token",
    "userinfo_endpoint": "https://localhost:44388/connect/userinfo",
    "end_session_endpoint": "https://localhost:44388/connect/endsession",
    "check_session_iframe": "https://localhost:44388/connect/checksession",
    "revocation_endpoint": "https://localhost:44388/connect/revocation",
    "introspection_endpoint": "https://localhost:44388/connect/introspect",
    "device_authorization_endpoint": "https://localhost:44388/connect/deviceauthorization",
    "frontchannel_logout_supported": true,
    "frontchannel_logout_session_supported": true,
    "backchannel_logout_supported": true,
    "backchannel_logout_session_supported": true,
    "scopes_supported": [
        "openid",
        "profile",
        "WebApplication4.ServerAPI",
        "offline_access"
    ],
    "claims_supported": [
        "sub",
        "name",
        "family_name",
        "given_name",
        "middle_name",
        "nickname",
        "preferred_username",
        "profile",
        "picture",
        "website",
        "gender",
        "birthdate",
        "zoneinfo",
        "locale",
        "updated_at"
    ],
    "grant_types_supported": [
        "authorization_code",
        "client_credentials",
        "refresh_token",
        "implicit",
        "password",
        "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code"
    ],
    "response_types_supported": [
        "code",
        "token",
        "id_token",
        "id_token token",
        "code id_token",
        "code token",
        "code id_token token"
    ],
    "response_modes_supported": [
        "form_post",
        "query",
        "fragment"
    ],
    "token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
        "client_secret_basic",
        "client_secret_post"
    ],
    "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported": [
        "RS256"
    ],
    "subject_types_supported": [
        "public"
    ],
    "code_challenge_methods_supported": [
        "plain",
        "S256"
    ],
    "request_parameter_supported": true
}
```

For some reason `IdentityServer` `Clients` can not be configured in code and in `appsettings.json`. I therefore removed `Clients` from `appsettings.json` and added this to Startup.cs:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.Clients.AddIdentityServerSPA("WebApplication4.Client", builder =>
        {
            builder.WithRedirectUri("/authentication/login-callback");
            builder.WithLogoutRedirectUri("/authentication/logout-callback");
        });
        options.Clients.Add(new IdentityServer4.Models.Client
        {
            ClientId = "WebApplication4.Integration",
            AllowedGrantTypes = { GrantType.ResourceOwnerPassword },
            AllowedScopes = { "WebApplication4.ServerAPI", "openid", "profile" }
        });
    });
```

Without `WithRedirectUri` and `WithLogoutRedirectUri` it did not work, `OidcConfigurationController` got an exception for `ClientRequestParametersProvider.GetClientParameters(HttpContext, clientId);` with `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains no elements'`. For some reason this is fixed automatically when using `appsettings.json`.

I now got the error message when posting to `/connect/token`:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_client"
}
```

But I got a much better error in the log:

```
Invalid client configuration for client WebApplication4.Integration: Client secret is required for password, but no client secret is configured.
```

Added a secret to `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.Clients.AddIdentityServerSPA("WebApplication4.Client", builder =>
        {
            builder.WithRedirectUri("/authentication/login-callback");
            builder.WithLogoutRedirectUri("/authentication/logout-callback");
        });
        options.Clients.Add(new IdentityServer4.Models.Client
        {
            ClientId = "WebApplication4.Integration",
            AllowedGrantTypes = { GrantType.ResourceOwnerPassword },
            //Use Configuration.GetSection("MySecretValue").Value; to get a value from appsettings.json
            ClientSecrets = { new Secret("MySecretValue".Sha256()) },
            AllowedScopes = { "WebApplication4.ServerAPI", "openid", "profile" }
        });
    });
```

And the request:

```
POST /connect/token HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:44388
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 168

grant_type=password&username=example%40example.com&password=Password1!&client_id=WebApplication4.Integration&scope=WebApplication4.ServerAPI&client_secret=MySecretValue
```

It finally worked and the normal login flow worked as well!

[image]