# Duende.IdentityServer from Blazor WebAssembly App protecting ASP.NET Core API using Client Credentials with custom allowed scope - invalid_scope

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-identity, duende-identity-server

I have a `Blazor WebAssembly App` created with `Microsoft Visual Studio` with these specifications: `Target Framework .NET 6.0`, `Authentication Type Individual Accounts` and `ASP.NET Core Hosted`:

Using this answer I have been able to add Client Credentials flow

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67324222/3850405

I removed this from `appsettings.json`:

```
"Clients": {
  "WebApplication4.Client": {
    "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
  }
}
```

Edit `Startup.cs` or `Program.cs`:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.Clients.AddIdentityServerSPA("WebApplication4.Client", builder =>
        {
            builder.WithRedirectUri("/authentication/login-callback");
            builder.WithLogoutRedirectUri("/authentication/logout-callback");
        });
        options.Clients.Add(new Duende.IdentityServer.Models.Client
        {
            ClientId = "WebApplication4.Integration",
            AllowedGrantTypes = { GrantType.ClientCredentials },
            ClientSecrets = { new Secret("MySecretValue".Sha256()) },
            AllowedScopes = { "WebApplication4.ServerAPI"}
        });
    });
```

This request will work:

```
POST /connect/token HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:44397
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=WebApplication4.Integration&client_secret=MySecretValue&scope=WebApplication4.ServerAPI
```

However I want this client to have its own `AllowedScopes`. If I then change `AllowedScopes = { "WebApplication4.ServerAPI"}` to `AllowedScopes = { "WebApplication4.IntegrationAPI"}` and of course modifying the request.

Server then responds with:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_scope"
}
```

If I look at logging I get the following history:

```
info: Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: Duende.IdentityServer.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint for /connect/token
info: Duende.IdentityServer.Events.DefaultEventService[0]
      {
        "ClientId": "WebApplication4.Integration",
        "AuthenticationMethod": "SharedSecret",
        "Category": "Authentication",
        "Name": "Client Authentication Success",
        "EventType": "Success",
        "Id": 1010,
        "ActivityId": "80000009-0014-d600-b63f-84710c7967bb",
        "TimeStamp": "2022-09-22T09:30:31Z",
        "ProcessId": 17768,
        "LocalIpAddress": "::1:44397",
        "RemoteIpAddress": "::1"
      }
fail: Duende.IdentityServer.Validation.DefaultResourceValidator[0]
      Scope WebApplication4.IntegrationAPI not found in store or not supported by requested resource indicators.
fail: Duende.IdentityServer.Validation.TokenRequestValidator[0]
      Invalid scopes requested, {
        "ClientId": "WebApplication4.Integration",
        "GrantType": "client_credentials",
        "AuthorizationCode": "********",
        "RefreshToken": "********",
        "Raw": {
          "grant_type": "client_credentials",
          "client_id": "WebApplication4.Integration",
          "client_secret": "***REDACTED***",
          "scope": "WebApplication4.IntegrationAPI"
        }
      }
info: Duende.IdentityServer.Events.DefaultEventService[0]
      {
        "ClientId": "WebApplication4.Integration",
        "Endpoint": "Token",
        "GrantType": "client_credentials",
        "Error": "invalid_scope",
        "Category": "Token",
        "Name": "Token Issued Failure",
        "EventType": "Failure",
        "Id": 2001,
        "ActivityId": "80000009-0014-d600-b63f-84710c7967bb",
        "TimeStamp": "2022-09-22T09:30:31Z",
        "ProcessId": 17768,
        "LocalIpAddress": "::1:44397",
        "RemoteIpAddress": "::1"
      }
```

What I take with me is this:

```
Scope WebApplication4.IntegrationAPI not found in store or not supported by requested resource indicators.
```

I then looked at these guides:

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/4632#issuecomment-654685880

https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/quickstarts/1_client_credentials/

I therefore added this code:

```
public static class Config
{
    public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> ApiScopes =>
        new List<ApiScope>
        {
        new ApiScope("WebApplication4.IntegrationAPI", "Integration API")
        };
}
```

and

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.ApiScopes)
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(options =>...
```

This still gave me the same error.

I then added a new list with clients:

```
public static IEnumerable<Duende.IdentityServer.Models.Client> Clients =>
    new List<Duende.IdentityServer.Models.Client>
    {
        new Duende.IdentityServer.Models.Client
        {
            ClientId = "WebApplication4.Integration",
            AllowedGrantTypes = { GrantType.ClientCredentials },
            ClientSecrets = { new Secret("MySecretValue".Sha256()) },
            AllowedScopes = { "WebApplication4.IntegrationAPI" },
        }
    };
```

Removed the old client from `AddApiAuthorization` and used this code instead:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.ApiScopes)
    .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(options => ...
```

This gave me a new error when requesting a token:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_client"
}
```

Logs:

```
info: Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: Duende.IdentityServer.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint for /connect/token
info: Duende.IdentityServer.Events.DefaultEventService[0]
      {
        "ClientId": "WebApplication4.Integration",
        "Category": "Authentication",
        "Name": "Client Authentication Failure",
        "EventType": "Failure",
        "Id": 1011,
        "Message": "Unknown client",
        "ActivityId": "8000000a-0016-e700-b63f-84710c7967bb",
        "TimeStamp": "2022-09-22T09:54:08Z",
        "ProcessId": 10676,
        "LocalIpAddress": "::1:44397",
        "RemoteIpAddress": "::1"
      }
fail: Duende.IdentityServer.Validation.ClientSecretValidator[0]
      No client with id 'WebApplication4.Integration' found. aborting
```

If I look at https://localhost:44397/.well-known/openid-configuration I only see `WebApplication4.ServerAPI` in `scopes_supported` no matter the configuration.

I want to do it like this so that I can add a policy like this later:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("IntegrationApiScope", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        policy.RequireClaim("scope", "WebApplication4.IntegrationAPI");
    });
});
```

Meaning that I only want Client Credentials flow to get the scope `WebApplication4.IntegrationAPI` and I don't want Authorization Code Grant, normal login flow via (`authorization_code`), to have this scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.ApiScopes.Add(new ApiScope("scope1"));
        options.Clients.AddIdentityServerSPA("WebApplication4.Client", builder =>
        {
            builder.WithRedirectUri("/authentication/login-callback");
            builder.WithLogoutRedirectUri("/authentication/logout-callback");
        });
        options.Clients.Add(new Duende.IdentityServer.Models.Client
        {
            ClientId = "WebApplication4.Integration",
            AllowedGrantTypes = { GrantType.ClientCredentials },
            ClientSecrets = { new Secret("MySecretValue".Sha256()) },
            AllowedScopes = { "scope1" }
        });
    });
```

However `WebApplication4.Integration` can still request the scope `WebApplication4.ServerAPI` and get a token with it.

Using the following code:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.ApiScopes.Add(new ApiScope("scope1"));
        options.ApiScopes.Add(new ApiScope("scope2"));
        options.Clients.Add(new Duende.IdentityServer.Models.Client
        {
            ClientId = "WebApplication4.Integration",
            AllowedGrantTypes = { GrantType.ClientCredentials },
            ClientSecrets = { new Secret("MySecretValue".Sha256()) },
            AllowedScopes = { "scope1" }
        });
    });
```

`WebApplication4.Integration` can get a token using scopes `WebApplication4.ServerAPI` and `scope1` but not with `scope2`.

See this issue for more info:

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/44122